# Laravel - Column not found orders.user_id

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I am designing a system where the user can subscribe to a plan and can also make single item payments. For the subscription part I am using [Laravel Mollie Cashier](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-mollie) and for the single item payment part I figured I could use the same tables that Cashier generates, which are `orders`, `order_items` and `subscriptions`.

I made a couple of models to tie all the tables together. So in the user model I've put the hasMany relation

```
public function orders() {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
```

And I made a Orders model where i've put the belongsTo model

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

The error I get is actually really obvious because the generated table `orders` does not have a user_id but instead is called `owner_id` (See below)

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('owner_type');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('owner_id');
            $table->string('number');
            $table->string('currency', 3)->nullable();
            $table->integer('subtotal');
            $table->integer('tax');
            $table->integer('total');
            $table->integer('balance_before')->default(0);
            $table->integer('credit_used')->default(0);
            $table->integer('total_due');
            $table->string('mollie_payment_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('mollie_payment_status', 16)->nullable();
            $table->datetime('processed_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I though I could fix this by adding the following line to the schema

`$table->foreign('owner_id')->references('id')->on('users');`

But this results in the same error. I tried adding `->nullable()` or `->unsigned()` to the `owner_id` field but that also gave the same result. How can I fix this issue so I can do a simple foreach loop like this?

```
@foreach($user->orders as $order):

@endforeach
```

NOTE: I can't simply change the `owner_id` to be called `user_id` because that will break Cashier-mollie. When a new subscription is created it inserts the Auth's ID into the `owner_id` field.

Answer (score 1):

since the model is User, and the column is not user_id, you must specify 2 connection keys.
the first is the column from the current table (owner_id)
and the second is a column from the users table (id)

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'owner_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the problem is but I guess in the orders Model:

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

you need to provide accoroding to laravel docs:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'other_key');
}
```

Laravel by default will look for User_id column, so if you using different name's you just need to specify them.